# Empirically determining the big-O runtime of a program?

Tags: performance, math, big-o, time-complexity

How would we be able to guess the big-O speed of a program given that we have the values of n and corresponding running times? Mind you, I do not come from a CS background and I have done some reading to put things in context, but am utterly clueless at this point.

Comment: Is this homework? I might first plot the values on a graph and see what that tells you.

Comment: What an odd question. Really - what *would* `n = 1000` and running time of `0:07` tell you? Unless you had a whole series of `n`, at which point it should be simple algebra...

Comment: Though phrased a little poorly, I think what he means is that he can query the run time for any given n (in which case it does become a simple 'best fit' approach.

Comment: Just wanted to add to Dave's good advice: use a log-log plot.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Dave - This isn't a homework question, but a question asked during screening for employment. I've plotted the values on a graph and it seems like a log chart, but am not certain.

Comment: To Yuck - I do have a series of n (and run times), but am still not certain as to how I would be able to guess the Big-O speed precisely. Thank you!

Comment: Also, the screening has already passed. I'm just doing this out of curiosity haha!

Comment: @FranklinCho: I think your approach should be correct. In practice we can plot the running time vs input size and then use a polynomial function to try to fit the plot to guess its algorithm complexity.

Answer (score 1):

There is really nothing that anyone can tell you that will help you answer a similar question in the future. I suggest that you read this book [Intro to algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) and try to understand the concept, if you need to answer these kind of questions in interviews, it may be a good use of your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general procedure for doing this that will always work, but there are many techniques that are powerful in general.

Let's assume that your program's runtime has one of the following "standard" forms:

- Polynomial: O(n<sup>k</sup>)
- Exponential: O(a<sup>n</sup>)

If it does have one of these forms, here are some useful techniques for determining the constants controlling the big-O expression.

### Polynomial time

If your function has runtime O(n<sup>k</sup>), then (for large n) the runtime will approximately be of the form T(n) = c·n<sup>k</sup>. A really useful technique for figuring out what c and k are is to use a [log-log plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-log_plot). Suppose that you look at the values of log T(n) and log (c · n<sup>k</sup>).  Note that

> log (c · n<sup>k</sup>) = log c + k log n

This means that if you have a log-log plot, where the dependent variable is log T(n) and the independent variable is log n, then any polynomial will come out as a line. You can then use any standard linear regression technique to get a best-fit line that matches the line, from which you can recover log c and k in the above expression. From there, the runtime of your algorithm will be O(n<sup>k</sup>)

### Exponential Time

If your runtime is exponential (that is, O(a<sup>n</sup>) for some a), then you can use a standard log plot to recover the base a. If your function is approximately T(n) = c · a<sup>n</sup> for some constants a and c, then taking the log of the right-hand side gives you

> log (c · a<sup>n</sup>) = log c + n log a

This means that if you plot T(n) versus log c + n log a, you'll get back some straight line. You can then do a regression to recover log c and log a, from which the runtime can be read off as O(a<sup>n</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can find it mathematically (which is the way guaranteed to give a correct result, unless you make mistakes which many do), or empirically (by doing measurements). The second method will *often* give the right results but can be tricked.

For an empirical result, I'd start with n = 1 to n = 10, then continue growing n by 10% each time, drawing a chart, until it takes too long. Algorithms using memory proportional to n often have a "jump" in execution time when your memory requirements go to the next cache level; increasing n by 10% means you can find these jumps.

And then there are algorithms where tiny changes in the data make huge differences in timing. For an NP-complete problem, some instances of the same problem can be very easy to solve, and some can be very hard. Or matrix multiplication, where the obvious (and slow) algorithm can have a *huge* variation in execution time depending on n.