# How to calculate run time complexity (`"O(m)"`) when given a real runtime?

Tags: performance, algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I try to ask it shortly:

I have a algorithm, as a function, let call it `f`:

```
void f(int[1..N]) {
   // algorithm goes here
}
```

Now, I have the `real runtime` for a `N` input.

Please assume that the function `time()` returns the current system's time in milliseconds.

```
int[1...N] n;
unsigned long start = time(), end; 
f(N); 
end = time();
printf("Real runtime: %ul", end - start);
```

So in other words, I know how many milliseconds will `f` run for argument `N`.

By this information, how can I calculate `f(N)` run time complexity, i.e. `f = O(N)`?

Comment: Time-complexity is a conceptual tool to help you think about algorithms. I am not sure if trying to determine it using timers (if possible at all) is useful in any way.

Comment: @Wilbert I need to do this in my homework

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empirically determining the big-O runtime of a program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620054/empirically-determining-the-big-o-runtime-of-a-program)

Comment: @Wilbert - it may be useful if you have 2 black-box algorithms (lib functions for e.g.), and you want to discover which one is superior asymptotically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need several data points for different N.

Let's say you get these statistics:

```
N     time(ms)
4       12
8       24
16      48
```

In this case doubling N doubles the time, so your complexity must be O(N).

But if you get these stats

```
N     time(ms)
4       16
8       64
16      256
```

In this case doubling n quadruples the runtime, so you complexity must be O(n2).

If time does not change at all, your complexity is O(1)

Similarly, different data points will let you determine the function that satisfies the big(O). The more points you have for different N, the better you can determine that function.

Comment: Point to note: you are not going to get numbers anywhere near as nice from an actual program. Also constant factors.

Comment: @millimoose Yes I agree :) but it really depends on how accurate the measurement tool is.

Comment: If anyone wants to know more about this topic it is usually called "curve fitting".

Comment: @slider I assumed it's wall clock time, I guess for the purposes of the assignment it could be a counter.

Comment: @sdasdadas I think the greater point is that expecting people to do nontrivial curve fitting for what's likely an introduction to algorithm complexity seems odd. (Or doing curve fitting to deal with real-world performance problems at all for that matter. It's just not a very practical tool.) Also going by wiki, "curve fitting" isn't really "figuring out which arbitrary function is behind these data points", but "find some function that approximates these data points, not necessarily of the same type as the one that generated them".

Comment: @millimoose I agree with you about the course - I wanted to throw it up for future readers who might have a different application. You're right that curve fitting can't give you back the function that's behind the data. But it will probably be enough for you to determine linear, logn, n, n^2, etc.